# Base conversion c

Tags: c

Please help me. So this is my code. I'm trying to convert an integer using recursion right now, and I'm having a problem. I can't make the 0 to exit. Thanks in advance!

```
#include <stdio.h>

void convert_basis(int num,int base) {
    if(num > 0) {
        int rem = (num % base);
        convert_basis(num / base, base);
        printf("%d",rem);
    }
}

int main() {
    int num, base;
    printf("\t\t\tBase Conversion Numbers\n");
    printf("=============================================\n\n");

    do {
        printf("Input the numbers that you want to search[1-100][0 to exit]: ");
        scanf("%d", &num);
        fflush(stdin);
    } while (num<1 || num>100);

    do {
        printf("Input the number of base [2-20]: ");
        scanf("%d", &base);
        fflush(stdin);
    } while (base<2 || base>20);

    printf("\n\n");
    int flag=base;
    for(int i=flag; i>1; i--) {
        printf("Number %d in base %d is : ", num, base);
        convert_basis(num,base);
        base--;
        printf("\n");
    }
    printf("\n\nPress enter to continue.......");
    getchar();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: where you got stuck?...in the for loop??

Comment: This looks like straight up C. You sure you are working in C++?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try:

```
do {
    printf("Input the numbers that you want to search[1-100][0 to exit]: ");
    scanf("%d", &num);
    fflush(stdin);
    // Exit when user enters 0
    if (num == 0)
        return 0;
} while (num<1 || num>100);
```

Alternatively you could use `exit(0);` rather than `return 0`, especially if you want to exit in a different function than `main`.

Comment: Some explanation would be nice.

Comment: @sgvd the original code appears to get the original number only once (as a value between 1 and 100), exit from the do loop immediately, and exit from the main after doing the calculation. As a result, this change should not cause any change in the execution.

Comment: @phresnel: which bit is unclear? it's just a check whether the input is 0 and exits the program if it is, as indicated by the printed message.

Comment: @sabbahillel: the first `do` loop in the original code keeps looking if a number is entered outside of the [1, 100] range. So an input of 0 would just result in another print of 'Input the numbers...'. My change makes it actually exit then

Comment: Note that the code should explicitly test that `scanf()` is successful, bailing out if it is not.  `if (scanf("%d", &num) != 1) { ...bail out... }`.  If the input contains a letter 'a' and the last number entered was 10, you run into problems.  Also note that `fflush(stdin);` only works reliably on Windows (but there it resolves the 'letter jamming the works' problem).

Comment: @sgvd If I read the code correctly, entering a number to be converted (in the first do) will then exit that do, get a base (in the same way) perform the convert and then get to the "press enter to exit" Looking at the question, I now realize that the OP wanted to have a 0 entry in that first do loop force an exit. I did not understand that and thought he was talking about a problem with the recursion. Since the conversion of a number will always cause an exit from main, there is no point in the forced exit. He should set up an outer loop to keep converting until a 0 is entered.

Answer (score 0):

Note.

```
    printf("\n\nPress enter to continue.......");
    getchar();
    return 0;
}
```

will always exit the main program. If you wanted to do another entry, you need to surround the input do loops and the recursion logic with a loop. Then you can use a 0 to force an exit from the first input do loop as suggested by @sgvd